# In how many ways does a Lie algebra decompose as an orthogonal direct sum of Cartans?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, lie-algebras, exceptional-groups

For a prime $p$, the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(p)$ can be decomposed into an orthogonal direct sum of $p+1$ Cartan subalgebras as follows. Consider the [clock and shift matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices#Construction:_The_clock_and_shift_matrices) — these are a pair of order-$p$ matrices which do not commute in $\mathrm{SU}(p)$, and hence are not simultaneously diagonalizable, but do commute in $\mathrm{PSU}(p)$. In fact, they generate a maximal abelian subgroup of $\mathrm{PSU}(p)$, which is elementary of order $p^2$; I'll call this subgroup $T_p \subset \mathrm{PSU}(p)$ to remind you of a Cartan torus. The normalizer of $T_p$ acts transitively on the nonzero elements of $T_p$ (they are all conjugate). Decompose $\mathfrak{su}(p)\otimes \mathbb C$ into eigenspaces for the $T_p$: the weight-zero eigenspace vanishes because $T_p$ is maximal abelian, and the others all have the same dimension because of the transitivity of the normalizer. So each eigenspace is $1$-dimensional. Each line in $T_p^\vee := \hom(T_p, \mathrm{U}(1)) \cong \mathbb{F}_p^2$ sums to a $(p-1)$-dimensional Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{su}(p)$ because of the gradings. In fact, this subalgebra is commutative, hence a Cartan. All together, we find
$$ \mathfrak{su}(p) = \bigoplus_{x \in \mathbb{F}_pP^1} \text{Cartan}$$
where $\mathbb{F}_pP^1$ is the projective line over $\mathbb{F}_p$. This is an orthogonal direct sum because the Killing form is $T_p$-invariant, and hence only pairs eigenvectors of opposite weights.

I know a similar construction in a few other cases. The exceptional group $G_2$ contains a maximal abelian subgroup $T_2 \subset G_2$ which is elementary of order $2^3$. (For example, the grading group of the octonian algebra $\mathbb{O}$.) Again its normalizer is transitive, and so $\mathfrak{g}_2$ decomposes into a sum of weight spaces indexed by the $7$ nonzero elements of $T_2^\vee$, and all the nonzero weight spaces are the same dimension. Hence this dimension is $2$, and they are all Cartans.
Similarly, $F_4$ contains a maximal abelian subgroup which is elementary of order $3^3$, and $E_8$ contains a maximal abelian subgroup which is elementary of order $5^3$. By summing over the lines in these three-dimensional spaces, you find:
$$ G_2 = \bigoplus_{x \in \mathbb{F}_2P^2} \text{Cartan}, \qquad F_4 = \bigoplus_{x \in \mathbb{F}_3P^2} \text{Cartan}, \qquad E_8 = \bigoplus_{x \in \mathbb{F}_5P^2} \text{Cartan}.$$
Again these direct sums are orthogonal because the Killing form only pairs opposite weights.

$E_8$ also has another maximal abelian subgroup which is elementary of order $2^5$. This provides an orthogonal direct sum decomposition as
$$ E_8 = \bigoplus_{x \in \mathbb{F}_2 P^4} \text{Cartan}.$$
[These two direct sum decompositions of $E_8$ into Cartans are not equivalent.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/339374/8-times-31-8-times-31/467290#467290)

Is this how every orthogonal direct sum decomposition is built? Under some transitivity and/or irreducibility assumptions, it seems from [Alexei Kostrikin and Pham Huu Tiep, *Orthogonal Decompositions and Integral Lattices*, 1994](https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110901757) that the answer is yes. (I do not currently have access to more than the first page of each chapter, so I cannot check the details.) That book also indicates that, as of 1994, the general question of even whether $\mathfrak{su}(6)$ admits an (necessarily non-irreducible) orthogonal direct sum decomposition was open — this is rather whimsically called the "Winnie the Pooh problem", due, apparently, to a very funny Russian pun about $A_5$ that I have not been able to work out.

Has progress been made since 1994?

Comment: One caveat to "the answer is yes" is that Kostrikin and Tiep's construction of OD's in $A(p^m)$ is a bit more complicated. There is a copy of $\mathbb{Z}/(p \mathbb{Z})^{2m}$ in $PSU(p^m)$, for which $\mathfrak{su}(p^m)$ breaks into $p^{2m-1}$ one dimensional orthogonal eigenspaces indexed by the nonzero vectors in $\mathbb{F}_p^{2m}$. In order to group them into Cartans, one must partition the nonzero vectors of $\mathbb{F}_p^{2m}$ into sets $L$ of size $p^m-1$. (continued)

Comment: It turns out that $\mathbb{F}_p^{2m}$ is equipped with a natural symplectic form, and the natural condition is that each $L \cup \{ 0 \}$ is Lagrangian for this form. There are many different such partitions for $m>1$. This is Section 1.2 in the book, although I understand that you don't have access to this. (I have the whole book, but it's long!)